# 10-gon as connected sum of tori or projective plane

Tags: general-topology, geometry, surfaces

We're supposed to use cutting and gluing to find out, whether a given surface is a connected sum of tori or a connected sum of $\mathbb{R}P^2$. Now, there's one surface I'm stuck with. It is a 10-gon with edges (a,b,c,d,e) and presentation: $abcdea^{-1}b^{-1}c^{-1}d^{-1}e^{-1}$.

I connect the crossed opposing pairs and end up with $fgf^{-1}g^{-1}e^{-1}hjh^{-1}j^{-1}e$. But according to our book, this should not happen if all points are identified.

Does anybody see what's going wrong here?

Comment: It might be useful if you add a drawing, as it does not seem clear to me what you mean by "connect the crossed opposing pairs".

Comment: @Matt see here: https://imgur.com/a/CI3BIkL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because not all the points are identified. In fact, they are divided into two groups of five, each of which is identified as a separate point. See the diagram below and try to chase them.

[image]

Comment: I see. This would make sense. However, I can see only the argument that it is possible that not all points are identified. How to prove this fact?

Comment: To prove which fact? I thought your question was why you got a relation when all the points were identified.

Comment: Ah, yes. Of course. Thank you.